# Как синхронизировать перечисление в коде с колонкой в БД?

Tags: база-данных, spring, hibernate, orm, enum

**spring+hibernate**

Есть сущность `User` с enum-свойством `status`

```
User {
    int id;
    String username;
    String password;
    Status status;
}

enum Status {
    ACTIVE, DELETED
}
```

В базе данных есть связанная с сущностью таблица `db.users`.

Суть в следующем:

Если поле `db.users.status` имеет тип `VARCHAR`, при добавлении строки оно может быть заполнено напрямую, с помощью метода name() (`Status.DELETED.name()`). Однако если в будущем кто-то изменит перечисление, ( `Status.DELETED` превратится в `Status.REMOVED`), поля колонки останутся прежними.

Тогда можно сделать тип колонки `db.users.status` равным `INT`, и либо создать int-свойство в нашем перечислении, либо реализовать какой-нибудь AttributeConverter. В обоих случаях статусы имели бы свои номера, которыми мы могли бы заполнить соответствующую колонку. Данный подход в каком-то смысле решает проблему выше, однако если в коде по какой-то причине изменились статусы, та же история может случиться и с их номерами, да и колонка таблицы в этом случае становится менее читабельной.

Как можно решить проблему синхронизации? Какой подход считается наиболее предпочтительным в таких ситуациях?

Answer (score 0):

Числовые идентификаторы лучше, так как их нет смысла изменять намеренно.

А от случайного изменения защищает юнит тест, который проверяет соответствие числовых констант и значений enum-a. Если кто-то случайно изменит - тест упадет с соответствующим сообщением. Тогда разработчик примет решение, действительно ли он хочет изменить константу (а значит и написать миграцию БД) или все же откатить это изменение.